# How can I convert this file into a sqlite data base?

Tags: database, sqlite, text

I have a text file representation of a database. It has tables names and records as shown bellow:

```
TABLE:  "ACTIVE DEGREES OF FREEDOM"
UX=Yes   UY=Yes   UZ=Yes   RX=Yes   RY=Yes   RZ=Yes

TABLE:  "ANALYSIS OPTIONS"
Solver=Advanced   SolverProc=Auto     StiffCase=None   GeomMod=None   

TABLE:  "COORDINATE SYSTEMS"
Name=GLOBAL   X=0   Y=0   Z=0   AboutZ=0   AboutY=0   AboutX=0

TABLE:  "JOINT COORDINATES"
   Joint=1   CoordSys=GLOBAL   CoordType=Cartesian   XorR=-720   Y=-432   Z=0   
   Joint=2   CoordSys=GLOBAL   CoordType=Cartesian   XorR=-720   Y=-432   Z=144 
   Joint=3   CoordSys=GLOBAL   CoordType=Cartesian   XorR=-720   Y=-432   Z=288 
   Joint=4   CoordSys=GLOBAL   CoordType=Cartesian   XorR=-720   Y=-432   Z=432 
   Joint=5   CoordSys=GLOBAL   CoordType=Cartesian   XorR=-720   Y=-432   Z=576 
   Joint=6   CoordSys=GLOBAL   CoordType=Cartesian   XorR=-720   Y=-144   Z=0   

....
```

is there a tool to do the conversion of this text file to sqlite possible with minimum amount of explicit type information ?
There is an empty line after each table to indicate the table is finished. for each row, there is an underline "_" at the end to indicate the row is not finished and it is to be continued in the next line. 
Name of the table is given and some values that have space in them are quoted. This is basically all the information there is in the text.

Comment: If this is not a standard data format, you will have to write your own parser and to insert the result into a sqlite db yourself. What extension do these files have? (It might or might not point to a known data format)

Comment: the file is *.s2k, produced by Sap2000 or Etabs which is a finite element program.